# Не создаётся css файл

Tags: html, css

Не создаётся css файл , хотя могу создать файл с расширением .html что делать ?
[image: В изображение показано что у меня не создаётся файл css но создаётся файл html]

Comment: у вас по факту tests.css.txt то есть надо поменять расширение файла а не название

Comment: А почему вы думаете, что он не является .css файлом? Потому что иконка блокнота?

Comment: Она в меня работает но я не могу открыть ее с Edge . Нажимаю "Открыть с помощью " и там нет Edge

Answer (score -1):

Тебе и не надо браузер подключать, с файлом у тебя все норм. Его нужно подключать к html документу, вот написал как это сделать(вставлять фрагмент в html)

```html
<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```